How to open static html from Shared folder using anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC
I want to open a static html (help) file from the _Layout page. I have added
<a class="btn btn-green" target="_blank" href="spexhelp.cshtml">Help</a></div>

But this is not working. How to access this URL to open in a new page?


Is your help file actually static? The .cshtml extension indicates that it is not.

To answer your question, you cannot directly call the View from the anchor tag as it is against the tenants of MVC pattern.
If you do this:
<a class="btn btn-green" target="_blank" href="~/Views/Shared/spexhelp.cshtml">Help</a>

This will give you a 404 not found error.
Therefore you need to create an action method first. For example if I have a HomeController, I will create an action method first:
public ActionResult spexhelp()
{
    return View();
}

And then call it from the View like this:
<a class="btn btn-green" target="_blank" href="~/Home/spexhelp">Help</a>

You can also use Url.Action helper to generate the link:
<a class="btn btn-green" target="_blank" href="@Url.Action("spexhelp", "Home")">Help</a>

The controller will then look for the spexhelp.cshtml in the Shared folder and render it as required.
You can of course pass the name of the View directly while returning it from the Controller if you do not want to use the same name for your action method as the view name in this case.
For example you can keep the name of your action method different from your View file name:
public ActionResult Help()
{
    return View("~/Views/Shared/spexhelp.cshtml");
}

Here your a tag will be:
<a class="btn btn-green" target="_blank" href="~/Home/Help">Help</a>

